# Reading nested values within json file - with JS

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I'm trying to read values from a JSON file.
So far I can read down to stopTime but I cannot work out how to read the nested values after that.

My JSON file

```
 "description": [
    {
    "id": " an id number",
    "something 1": "xxxx",
    "something 2": "yyyy",
    "startTime": "2017-12-27T18:47:15.000+0000",
    "stopTime": "2017-12-27T18:47:15.000+0000",
    "mediaFiles": [
        {
        "mediaUri": " some url value",
        "mediaPath": "some path value",
        "startTime": " a time",
```

My JS code which works.

```
var J = [];
$.getJSON( "calls/jsonfile.json", function( data){
  J = data;
  var x = 48;
  for(x=0;x<48;++x) {
     var id = J.description[x].id;
     ...
  }
}
```

This works well and i get the values i'm looking for.

Any help greatly appreciated... I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: what do you want to retrieve from the nested values?, how do you want it formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(x=0;x<48;++x) {
    var id = J.description[x].id;
    // You can loop over the mediaFiles like this:
    for( num in J.description[x].mediaFiles ) {
        var theURI  = J.description[x].mediaFiles[num].mediaUri
        var thePath = J.description[x].mediaFiles[num].mediaPath
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly thanks... I was still editing my question to make it easy to read when Magmatrix answered.

Comment: Now, i've found there is another nested group of  "parameters": {
                        "dateTime": "2017-12-27T18:47:15Z",

Comment: I've found that inside the mediaFiles there is this. 
 "parameters": {
                        "dateTime": "2017-12-27T18:47:15Z",
                        "rp.xx_auth": "user:pass",
                        "rp.xx_uri": "http://xxx",
                        "sipsAppName": "an app",
                        "number": "7771",
                        "connId": "000102afa52ba013",
                        "dnis": "8881"
                                        },
How do I read this inside the mediaFiles ?

Comment: var datetime = J.description[x].mediaFiles[num].parameters.dateTime;
var userpass = J.description[x].mediaFiles[num].parameters.['rp.xx_auth'];
...and so on. if the key has special characters (dot, colon. etc) then use brackets and quote it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, don't hardcode `x < 48`. Use `J.description.length`, so that your code will always perform correctly regardless of the actual length of the array.

You want something like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < J.description.length; x++) {
    var descEntry = J.description[x];
    var id = descEntry.id;
    // do stuff with the description entry
    ...

    for (var y = 0; y < descEntry.mediaFiles.length; y++) {
        var fileEntry = descEntry.mediaFiles[y];
        // do stuff with the file entry
        ...
    }
}
```

The first for-loop will iterate `x` over all of the indices of `J.description`. I added a variable for the current entry to simplify things. The second for-loop will iterate `y` over all of the indices of `descEntry.mediaFiles` (aka `J.description[x].mediaFiles`).

Same thing, using for-each loops to iterate over array keys (indices):

```
for (var x in J.description) {
    var descEntry = J.description[x];
    var id = descEntry.id;
    // do stuff with the description entry
    ...

    for (var y in descEntry.mediaFiles) {
        var fileEntry = descEntry.mediaFiles[y];
        // do stuff with the file entry
        ...
    }
}
```

Same thing, using [**new ES2015 features**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for-each loops to iterate over array values:

```
for (var descEntry of J.description) {
    var id = descEntry.id;
    // do stuff with the description entry
    ...

    for (var fileEntry of descEntry.mediaFiles) {
        // do stuff with the file entry
        ...
    }
}
```

**Your JavaScript environment might not support ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) features.** Additionally, `for...in` loops can do weird things if you try iterating over a non-standard array (say, one to which extra properties have been added).

Answer (score 0):

You could use some basic functional javascript to get the values from your json array. using just a few functions you can compose the ability to get any value from your collection of data.

- **compose** - joins multiple functions
- **flatMap** - flattens a 2 level array, running a function over each value
- **map** - runs a function over each element in an array, returning a new array with the new values
- **prop** - get's a property of an object

The benefit of using functional programming is you can create little applications by combining individually testable functions. And you can get these functions from a library like [ramdajs](http://ramdajs.com).

```js
const json = {
  "description": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "mediaFiles": [
        { "mediaUri": "/images/1_1.png" },
        { "mediaUri": "/images/1_2.png" },
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "mediaFiles": [
        { "mediaUri": "/images/2_1.png" },
        { "mediaUri": "/images/2_2.png" },
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const prop = name => obj => obj[name]
const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((x, fn) => fn(x), x)
const map = fn => arr => arr.map(fn)
const flatMap = fn => arr => arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(fn(x)), [])

const getIds = compose(
  map(prop('id')),
  prop('description')
)

const getMediaUris = compose(
  flatMap(
    compose(
      map(prop('mediaUri')),
      prop('mediaFiles')
    )
  ),
  prop('description')
)

console.log(
  getIds(json)
)

console.log(
  getMediaUris(json)
)

expect('prop retrieves an object property', () => {
  assert(
    prop('one')({ one: 1 })
  ).equal(1)
})

expect('compose joins multiple functions', () => {
  assert(
    compose(
      z => z + 1,
      y => y + 1,
      x => x + 1
    )(0)
  ).equal(3)
})

expect('flatMap folds array', () => {
  assert(
    flatMap(x => x)([[1], [2]])
  ).deepEqual([1, 2])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```